# How to read a Class[] values from a nested annotation in an annotation processor

Tags: java, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I am trying to generate some code using Java annotation processing tools, I have nested annotations where the parent annotation value is an array of the child annotation, and the child annotation value is an array of classes.

Annotations:

```
public @interface ParentAnnotation {
    ChildAnnotation[] value();
}
public @interface ChildAnnotation {
    Class<?>[] value();
}
```

Usage:

```
@ParentAnnotation(
{
      @ChildAnnotation({Foo.class, Bar.class}),
      @ChildAnnotation({Goo.class, Doo.class})
})
public class Sample{
}
```

calling `value()` on the annotation with my `Processor` subtype fails with this exception:

```
Error:java: error while creating source file javax.lang.model.type.MirroredTypeException: Attempt to access Class object for TypeMirror org.dominokit.samples.layout.shared.extension.LayoutEvent
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.AnnotationProxyMaker$MirroredTypeExceptionProxy.generateException(AnnotationProxyMaker.java:308)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.value(Unknown Source)
    at org.dominokit.domino.apt.client.processors.module.client.presenters.PresenterProxySourceWriter.generateFireActivationEvent(PresenterProxySourceWriter.java:238)
    at org.dominokit.domino.apt.client.processors.module.client.presenters.PresenterProxySourceWriter.asTypeBuilder(PresenterProxySourceWriter.java:64)
    at org.dominokit.domino.apt.client.processors.module.client.presenters.PresenterProxyProcessingStep.generateProxy(PresenterProxyProcessingStep.java:66)
    at org.dominokit.domino.apt.client.processors.module.client.presenters.PresenterProxyProcessingStep.process(PresenterProxyProcessingStep.java:53)
    at org.dominokit.domino.apt.client.processors.module.client.presenters.PresenterProxyProcessor.process(PresenterProxyProcessor.java:61)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:196)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:448)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:318)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:243)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:201)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1327)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1007)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1074)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:968)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:797)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:375)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:229)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

so how i can read these classes from the annotation as a `List<TypeMirror>` ?

Comment: "fails with exception" What exception? Post the stack trace.

Comment: I don't think annotations can accept instances of Class as parameter

Comment: @Stultuske They can. Have you never written a test annotated with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` ?

Comment: @Michael you're right .. dumb remark of mine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of debugging and trying one thing at a time i found the solution for this, the idea was in how to use the `AnnotationMirror` to obtain `AnnotationValue`, there was some sort of confusion at some point where the expected return types to be `AnnotationValue[]` was actually `List<AnnotationValue>`, below is a utility method i wrote to read the classes as a `List<List<TypeMirror>>` :

```
private List<List<TypeMirror>> getNestedAnnotationClassesValue(Element element){

        List<List<TypeMirror>> classesInAnntation = new ArrayList<>();
        if (nonNull(element.getAnnotation(ParentAnnotation.class))) {
            List<? extends AnnotationMirror> annotations = element.getAnnotationMirrors();
            for (AnnotationMirror annotationMirror : annotations) {
                if (types.isSameType(annotationMirror.getAnnotationType(), elements.getTypeElement(ParentAnnotation.class.getName()).asType())) {
                    Map<? extends ExecutableElement, ? extends AnnotationValue> elementValues = annotationMirror.getElementValues();

                    elementValues.values()
                            .stream()
                            .findFirst()
                            .ifPresent(annotationValue -> {
                                List<AnnotationMirror> childAnnotations = (List<AnnotationMirror>) annotationValue.getValue();
                                childAnnotations.stream()
                                        .forEach(childAnnotationMirror -> {
                                            Collection<? extends AnnotationValue> values = childAnnotationMirror.getElementValues()
                                                    .values();
                                            AnnotationValue childAnnotationValue = values.stream().findFirst().get();
                                            List<AnnotationValue> classesInNestedAnnotation = (List<AnnotationValue>) childAnnotationValue.getValue();
                                            Iterator<? extends AnnotationValue> iterator = classesInNestedAnnotation.iterator();

                                            List<TypeMirror> typeMirrorsInNestedAnnotation = new ArrayList<>();

                                            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                                                AnnotationValue next = iterator.next();
                                                typeMirrorsInNestedAnnotation.add((TypeMirror) next.getValue());
                                            }

                                            if (!typeMirrorsInNestedAnnotation.isEmpty()) {
                                                classesInAnntation.add(typeMirrorsInNestedAnnotation);
                                            }
                                        });
                            });
                }
            }
        }
        return classesInAnntation;
    }
```

Comment: i got `lambada expression not supported language level 7` syntax error . i am in the same situation except i have `Class[] classes();` in my annotation parameter . could you help me with it? it's really confusing!

Comment: @lvl4fi4 You need to compile with a langauge level 8 or above , or you can replace the lambdas in my code with standard code.

Comment: never mind i fount more simple solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52793839/2979171  thanks anyway.

Comment: I would not prefer to depend on an exception to solve this problem, things might behave in a different way with different environments.

Comment: well, it's suppose to work in Source ,not runtime so, i'm fine with it for now.

Comment: Yes i mean environment like Intellij vs Eclipse or different java versions. i am not saying it is wrong, but might need more testing to confirm it works.

Comment: I really appreciate your concerns , but it's kind of personal use not commercial but unless it breaks my code then i have to fix it .I'm using it to generate source code of my project which is `mvp` architect and so far it works for all of my classes .However if it breaks my source code, I will consider using your method which I'm pretty sure is the right way.